# Functions satisfying $Af(x) + B = f(Cx)$

Tags: functions, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $Af(x) + B = f(Cx)$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. Here the constants satisfies $A \in (0,1), B>0, C>1$.

Can we find $f$, or even it is unique?

Comment: The usual questions: What have you tried? Where did your work go bad?

Comment: @MasB I'm trying to use the contraction mapping theorem, but not sure I can use the sup norm like the other problems [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1574568/1213466) because the domain of function is unbounded.

Comment: @MasB And I want to find a closed form that satisfies the conditions above!

Comment: Maybe my solution to this similar (closed) [Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756338/solving-functional-equation-using-theoretical-techniques/4756393#4756393) can help you!

Comment: Note $x=0\implies f(0)=\frac{B}{1-A}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try common function patterns. One you might try is a power function $kx^\alpha$. Except the presence of the $B$ here might make you try $f(x)=kx^\alpha+b$.

When you try such a function in your relation, can you work out what things like $k,\alpha,b$ would have to be in terms of $A,B,C$?